# Reversed equal sign

Tags: excel, vba

I got a question regarding a code. I'm not sure if it is doable, I've tried to find the answer for it.

However, is it possible to reverse the equal sign in the codes?

Example code:

```
Worksheets("Example").Cells(1, 1).value = Me.checkbox1.value
```

This will give the Cell A1 the Value True or False.

But if I want to make it the other way around? That the data from A1 gives me the value for the checkbox?

With only 1 line of code like this it's easy to just retype it, but if you have 100s of codes from a userform it's annoying and just takes a lot of time.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd add a Tag value to the control specifying where to get the data from and then cycle through each control on the form and read the tag.

Comment: You'll have to change each line in the code. This shows you how important it is to design your code well, so that you *don't* have 100s of lines like that.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how to avoid large number of codes with large userforms.

Comment: Export the module, modify it in an editor that has a good regex search and replace, then reimport it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the sample form:
[image]

Each checkbox has a Tag value set in the properties:
[image]

When `CommandButton1` is pressed:
If the Toggle button isn't pressed the code will read the tag value and copy the data from the sheet to the form.

If the Toggle button is pressed the code will read the tag value and copy the data from the form to the sheet.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ctrl As Control
    Dim vTag As Variant

    For Each ctrl In UserForm1.Controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then
            vTag = Split(ctrl.Tag, "|")

            If UserForm1.ToggleButton1 Then
                ctrl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(vTag(0)).Range(vTag(1))
            Else
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(vTag(0)).Range(vTag(1)) = ctrl
            End If
        End If
    Next ctrl
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

**Approach 1**

- Copy the statements you wish to reverse to a worksheet starting at cell A1.
- Set cell B1 to formula: =FIND("=",A1)
- Set cell C1 to formula: =MID(A1,B1+1,LEN(A1)-B1)&" = " & MID(A1,1,B1-1)
- Copy cells B1 and C1 down
- Cells C1 and down will contain the statements you want ready to copy back to the module or form.

This approach will be adequate if the statements to reverse are in a small number of blocks.  If the statements are spread out through the module or form, this will be better than retyping but not as convenient as one would want.  If they are spread out. please give more information about the modules and or forms containing the statements.

**Edit**

Rereading the above, I realised an image would help:

[image: Image of Excel formulae being used to reverse assignments]

Most of the assignments are not very imaginative but you can see the idea. I assume most of you assignments are in two blocks: (1) worksheet to form and (2) back again. If this is the case, it is all very simple.